# SQL, Recursive Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please help me with my query i am currently working with selecting all the data's from tables with which i wanted to display all fields connected to other fields using recursive query.

My Table is

[image]

I have my self a query but i does'nt output all connected and all connected fibers my query is

```
select closure_id, fiber_id , @pv:=fiber_id as 'fiber_id2' 
from 
    (select * from tbl_map_closure_fiber order by closure_id) a
join
    (select @pv:=1)tmp

where closure_id=@pv
```

[image]

Just askin how can i manage to ouput both connected closure_id and connected fiber. please some one help .

Comment: Please post your table as plain text, not an image, so people can copy it to fiddles.

Comment: Or make a sqlfiddle yourself with the sample data.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but you probably need to join the table with itself.

Comment: wait ill post my sql fiddle here

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f83ee/1

Comment: what i actually wanted to do is to select all closure_id and fiber_id not only 1 field but all fields that are associated to each.

Comment: Then you should join the table to itself on `t1.closure_id = t2.fiber_id`

Comment: where and how  can i add that ?

Comment: can you please edit my sqlfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table with itself to pair up the related rows.

```
select t1.fiber_id, t2.fiber_id as fiber_id2
from tbl_map_closure_fiber AS t1
join tbl_map_closure_fiber AS t2
on t1.fiber_id = t2.closure_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f83ee/2